# Beautiful soup: extracting xml value with cerain attribute

Tags: xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using [this script](https://github.com/ThaWeatherman/scrapers/blob/master/boardgamegeek/get_game_info.py) to scrape boardgamegeek.

This is working fine and is getting the info out of the [xml data](https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=152179)

I want to extract one more element to the output csv. This one:

```
<items>
 <item>
   <link type="boardgamepublisher" id="1001" value="(Web published)"/>
   <link type="boardgamepublisher" id="1341" value="something else"/>
 </item>  
</items>
```

the id's are random, what I want is the value of the link tag of the type attribute "boardgamepublisher" and add them to a csv field (preferably all boardgamepublishers in one cell). sometimes the is one boardgamepublisher, sometimes more. there are a lot of link elements, so I need to filter by them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'xml')
    items = soup.find_all('item')
    for item in items:
```

This code needs to be added to add the publisher(s)

```
 publishers=item.find_all(type="boardgamepublisher" )
        gpublishers=""
        for publisher in publishers:
           gpublishers += publisher["value"]+","
```

first line returns the a list with

```
   <link type="boardgamepublisher" id="1001" value="(Web published)"/>
```

and

```
   <link type="boardgamepublisher" id="1341" value="something else"/>
```

the publisher["value"] extracts the content of the Value attribute.

I am still looking for better sugestions, because I am afriaght this solution will be really slow.